# MVC converting nullable decimal to string array for my model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a model with a decimal property. Whenever I try to edit/create an instance of the model I get an error upon validation when entering a nullable decimal field.

When I enter 1,5 it says the value must be a number (correct behaviour).

When I enter 1.5 however I get a false Modelstate due to "the model being not valid". Setting a breakpoint and checking the value for this item in the modelstate reveals that the raw value is string[1]. 
The error here reads: Value of '1,5' is not valid for this field

Anyone knows what could cause this?

Comment: Show the relevant code. And what is the culture on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is javascript uses point(.) for floating numbers and c# uses comma(,).

I solve this problem with this code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
    var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
    return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <= param[1]);
}

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```

You have to include [jquery.validate.min.js](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and [jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/) in your project.